# How to play a file on my cirrus audio card?

Tags: raspbian, audio-playback, wolfson-audio-card

The command for playing a file is "Play_to_Headset.sh" on Linux terminal.How do I select a particular file from LXMusic?

Comment: Cirrus Audio Card - for a Raspberry Pi? Seriously?

Comment: Yeah for my raspberry pi 2....It's a newer version of the Wolfson audio card.

Comment: I didn't know that! I thought it was a PCI card (I've got an old one in my PC - supported by Linux but NOT by Win7 8-P ).  For anyone else [this](http://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessories/cirrus_logic_audio_card/blog/2015/01/16/cirrus-logic-audio-card-2015-update) is the announcement for it on the Element14 (a Farnell brand-name and an Official Pi Manufacturer). It seems to be similar enough that the software will work the same as the Wolfson one (Wolfson Microelectronics was acquired by Cirrus Logic in 2014) but has the 40-Pin GPIO for later Pi models.

Comment: Answer: ./Playback_to_Headset.sh   <enter>                                                    aplay -c 2 -f S16_LE filename.wav <enter>

Comment: You may answer your own question Aisha - you may even get a bronze badge for doing so!  Just write up the above comment (with a bit more detail?) as an answer and then you can "Accept" it...